# Puzzle on a blackboard

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers, blackboard

[image]

What is the missing number in the picture above?(question is from some puzzle game) I tried some approaches, but haven't found any meaningful rule..thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! What puzzle game is this from? If a question is taken from somewhere else, you need to specify where exactly it's from.

Answer (score 1):

It can be assumed that evaluation is left to right (or rather: clockwise), not by precedence rules. Then this reads

> $$\frac{\frac{(x-9)\cdot 5}2-4+12}3+7=x$$

and simplifies to

> $$\frac56x+\frac{13}6=x $$

or

> $$ x=13.$$